# Virtualbox doesn't match with guest additions version

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, vagrant

I have installed the virtualbox from the **oracle** site not with my **ubuntu 14.04 repository**.

I've already downloaded the **virtualbox guest additions** that match my current **virtualbox** which is **5.0** from the oracle site.

Here are the steps that i followed to install the **virtualbox guest additions**. I did these steps in the **host** machine.

1. `sudo mnt -o loop ~/Downloads/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.0.iso /mnt`
2. `cd /mnt`
3. `sudo sh VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.0.iso`

But whenever i run `homestead up`, it shows that my virtualbox and virtualbox-guest-additions's version doesn't match.

This is the output whenever i run `homestead up`.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.14
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/chanhxc/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Codes => /home/chanhxc/Codes
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I wonder what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you execute the script from the guest additions "cd" to compile and make the guest additions?  I'm unfamiliar with the method you used to insert the "cd" - I just use the menu item - so I'm assuming you are running without a GUI or something.

Comment: i don't know if i understood you correctly. but i downloaded the guest additions.iso and run the scripts on the host machine.  yeah, i did run it without using the virtualbox GUI.

Comment: You have to insert the "cd" into the guest and run a script inside the guest to compile and make the additions.

Comment: Please take a look [vagrant-vbguest is a Vagrant plugin which automatically installs the host's VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest system](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)

Answer (score 11):

Try to add this plugin from the terminal:

```
sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

After installed and you do the 'vagrant up' it will detect the version between host and guest. If version doesn't match then it update the guest additions version accordingly. Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: install this, `homestead halt` then `homestead up` and you should see it will keep the guest additions up to date from now on +1!